# How to add a cookie when using TYPO3 Middleware?

Tags: cookies, typo3, typo3-10.x, psr-7

I want to use the Middleware to add a cookie.

In TYPO3 I have the `Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request` and the `Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface $handler` variables.

What is the best practise to add a cookie with all the needed settings (secure, domain, expire)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit interface in PSR for this since it basically boils down to sending a `Set-Cookie` header in the `$response`. You can either build that header yourself or use some packages which do this for you:

- https://packagist.org/packages/dflydev/fig-cookies
- https://packagist.org/packages/hansott/psr7-cookies

Answer (score 2):

My working code is now:

```php
$cookie = \Dflydev\FigCookies\SetCookie::create($name)
    ->withValue($value)
    ->withDomain($request->getAttribute('site')->getBase()->getHost())
    ->withSecure(true);

$response = new \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\RedirectResponse(
    (string)$request->getUri(),
    302,
    ['Set-Cookie' => (string)$cookie]
);
```

The cookie is set and I redirect the visitor so the cookie can also be read out by e.g. a TypoScript condition.