# TYPO3: How to use an external PHP Script (in fileadmin), where i can check the cookie

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I'm using TYPO3 11.3.3 for my server and i need a PHP Script, that can read and check the typo3_fe cookie. Are there any solutions? I can't use an extension and I have to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way would be a content object `USER`. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html).

Example

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = USER_INT
page.10 {
  userFunc = Vendor\ExtensionName\ExampleTime->printTime
}
```

---

However the doc also states

> The property includeLibs has been removed in TYPO3 8.0. In earlier
> versions the userFunc classes were sometimes stored in fileadmin/ -
> this is no longer possible out of the box and not recommended.
>
> **For the best result you should always, without exception, place your
> class files in an extension**, define composer class loading for this
> extension and add this extension as a dependency of your project.
> Then, your classes will load without issues when you refer to them by
> their class name.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly should the PHP script do apart from reading the cookie?
You can use a TypoScript condition to check if the cookie is present:

`[request.getCookieParams()['foo'] == 1]`

See the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Conditions/Index.html?highlight=cookie#request-getcookieparams) for details.

Comment: Can i put this line just in my PHP script? Or have i todo something else?

Comment: As I wrote it's TypoScript. So you need to put it into your TypoScript template. Please check the documentation on how [conditions in TyposScript](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Conditions.html#typoscript-syntax-conditions) work.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are being sent along with the request. With that being said, the best way to check for the cookies is Middlewares. With the middlewares you can check for the sent cookies and evaluate them with your script.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html) about middlewares.

This might be helpful as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/63951593/7162477

Best regards